# rsync wrong group ownership

Tags: permissions, rsync, backup

I recently made a full-system backup to a freshly ext4 formatted HDD using `sudo rsync -aPAXHhv ...` excluding the standard directories (/tmp, /mnt, /dev/, /sys, ...).
Today I mounted this HDD in a different system and, to my surprise, the `/home/foo` directory I backedup has the wrong group ownership. On `/home/foo` I get:

```
drwx------ 29 foo systemd-journal 4.0K Dec 22 13:29 foo
```

While the user is correct, the group is not, as it should be `users` instead of `systemd-journal`. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: What's the `gid` for the `users` group on the system being backed up?  What's the `gid` for the `systemd-journal` group on the system where the backup was mounted?

Comment: Ah! fair enough. Unfortunately I cannot check this right now since the backed up system is being repaired at the moment, but will do first thing once I get it back. Thanks!